# How do I write a native JavaScript plugin

Tags: javascript

I am looking to write a plugin which accepts a selector and also chain some methods.
How do I implement this plugin in native JavaScript?
Do I need to wrap it around self-invoking functions like this one below?

```
(function() {

})();
```

Comment: All up to you. If you want the plugin to be triggered straight away you can do it like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can chain functions by returning the value.

For example, chaining a function of an element, you could:

```
function makered(el) {
 el.style.background = 'red';
 return el;
}
```

and you should be able to do `makered(document.getElementById('something')).addEventListener()...` or any other function on element.

Self-invoking function couldn't be used in this case since you have to call this function somehow. jQuery plugins extend jQuery within a s.i.f., they do that so they don't make new variables that pollute global scope.